# Cheap PSU pcb - no output

Tags: power-supply, pcb

I ordered this PSU kit from aliexpress and I can't get it to work. Any ideas what I should test? There is no doc on this thing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: voltages at electrolytic caps
[image]

Comment: Measure the voltages across each of the electrolytic capacitors and mark them on the picture. This should give us an idea where the voltages have vanished.

Comment: Here is the schematic https://chinese-electronics-products-tested.blogspot.com/p/hiland-multiple-output-power-module.html

Answer (score 2):

Check **all** the part numbers, polarity (where applicable) and soldering.

At least one of the SS34 diodes appears to be backwards.

Comment: They were indeed backwards. I resoldered them with the correct polarity, still the psu gives no output. These inductor blocks have no polarity if I'm correct. Everything else seems ok..Could the diodes been damaged?

Comment: We dont have a schematic, but if I was to guess I would say if everything is now in correctly, perhaps the XL6008 is toast-  it looks to receive incoming power first after the self-resetting fuse.